# Add points to svg path using javascript

Tags: javascript, bezier

I have an SVG path in the form:

```
M352.793,422 C323.175,422 299.164,397.99 299.164,368.371 C299.164,338.753 323.175,314.742 352.793,314.742 C382.411,314.742 406.422,338.753 406.422,368.371 C406.422,397.99 382.411,422 352.793,422 z
```

And I want to add an arbitrary number of points to it, evenly distributed, without changing the shape, so ending up with something like this:

```
M352.793,422 C337.895,422 324.416,415.925 314.698,406.118 C305.095,396.427 299.164,383.092 299.164,368.371 C299.164,352.91 305.707,338.978 316.174,329.191 C325.759,320.228 338.635,314.742 352.793,314.742 C366.299,314.742 378.639,319.735 388.068,327.975 C399.316,337.806 406.422,352.259 406.422,368.371 C406.422,383.21 400.395,396.641 390.656,406.351 C380.956,416.021 367.572,422 352.793,422 z
```

I know it is mathematically possible, as it is defined by bezier curves, which themselves can be split at arbitrary points, without changing the curve, but it seems like a huge task to work out how to do that maths, and generate the new path string.

Are there any libraries that can help?

Comment: Do you know the points defining the bezier curve?

Comment: Only by parsing the SVG string, I am reading the SVG string from a file.

Answer (score 3):

From what I could find there is alot of javascript help for drawing bezier curver from the inital points, however I found none for reverse engineering. So the way I see it you have two possible approaches,

**1)**

Reverse engineering of the curve in order to get the original points, then recreate the curve with a lower `t_step`. The links below show the basic of how it is done.

[Reverse engineering Bezier curves](http://polymathprogrammer.com/2007/06/27/reverse-engineering-bezier-curves/)

[Reverse engineering a bezier curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032996/reverse-engineering-a-bezier-curve)

**2)**

Though you may lose some precision I feel like it should be possible to use cubic spline interpolation to estimate the curve between each point.

[Spline interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation)